# bash-script - merge two files at specific line

Tags: linux, bash

I'm struggling with two files, one contains my base64 certificate chain and the other one the private key and I want to merge them that the private key is added after the first occurence of

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

. I have no clue how to do it in bash.

Would be great to get help with it. Thank you!

**Certificate chain file**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate for your server)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the intermediate certificate)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the root certificate for the CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

**private key file**

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
    DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,CFCECC7976725DE5
    <Server Private Key – Passphrase protected>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**final merged file**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate for your server)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
    DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,CFCECC7976725DE5
    <Server Private Key – Passphrase protected>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the intermediate certificate)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the root certificate for the CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

script snippet:

```
get_new_certificate() {

    curl --get "$venafi_url$venafi_get_cert_endpoint?Format=Base64&IncludeChain=true&RootFirstOrder=false" --insecure --data-urlencode "CertificateDN=$certificate_identifier" \
    -H "accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $auth_token" \
    -o "$certificate_path"

   # Extract the private key block
   #private_key=$( awk '/-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----/,/-----END PRIVATE KEY-----/' "$PRIVATE_KEY_PATH" | tr '\n' '\f')
   private_key=$( cat "$PRIVATE_KEY_PATH")
   # Combine the certificates and private key in the desired order
   #sed -i -z "0,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/s/ $private_key"  "$certificate_path" |  tr '\f' '\n'
   #awk '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {print; print "'"$private_key"'"; next}1' "$cert_chain_files > "updated_combined.pem
   #cat $certificate_path
   sed -i.bak -e "/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/r $private_key" -e "/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/d" $certificate_path

   echo "Got new Certificate"
}
```

Comment: How do we know where it needs inserting? What did you try?

Comment: The private key must bei inserted after the first -----END CERTIFICATE----- as shown in the merge file example

Comment: If it needs inserting after the first occurrence of `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` you should say that in your question. You may have inserted it there because something in the certificate matches something in the key, or for some other reason - we don't know that and you didn't show any code.

Comment: Breaking the problem down into manageable chunks, it may be easiest to split the chain file based on the first found occurrence of `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` into two temporary files, then concatenate the two temporary chain files with the private key. I will try out some code now and add an answer if I can get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it simpler to approach this piece-wise, so:

- strip everything after end of first certificate from chain file
- show key file
- strip first certificate from chain file

---

So, to delete everything after end of first certificate in chain file:

```
sed '/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----/q' chain.txt
```

That just says to find the end of the certificate then quit with `q` command.

---

To concatenate the contents of the key file:

```
cat key.txt
```

---

To get rid of first certificate from chain file:

```
sed '1,/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----/d' chain.txt
```

That just says *"starting from line 1 and going till you find the end of the first certificate, delete whatever you see on the way"*.

---

## TL;DR

Then you can put those ideas together into a one-liner:

```
{ sed '/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----/q' chain.txt; cat key.txt; sed '1,/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----/d' chain.txt ; } > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, such a great approach!

Answer (score 1):

I will add my effort here:

**Example Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
certfile='chain.txt'
export privfile='private.txt'
export mergefile='output.txt'

touch $mergefile # Create output.txt if it doesn't already exist
true > $mergefile # Truncate output.txt

awk -v occur="1" '
{
    print >> ENVIRON["mergefile"] # Append text to output.txt 
}
/^-----END CERTIFICATE-----$/{
    count++
    
    # If the first occurrence of the match is found, do this
    if(count%occur==0){
        # Read in all lines from private.txt and append to output.txt 
        while((getline line<ENVIRON["privfile"]) > 0) {
           print line >> ENVIRON["mergefile"]
        }
    }
}
' $certfile

cat $mergefile # Output the contents of output.txt to STDOUT
```

**output.txt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certificate for your server)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
    DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,CFCECC7976725DE5
    <Server Private Key – Passphrase protected>
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the intermediate certificate)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (the root certificate for the CA)...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

This script uses awk to split the `chain.txt` file into separate sections based on a regular expression and appends them to `output.txt`. When the first occurrence of a match is found it also appends the complete contents of the `private.txt` file to `output.txt`. This script does not use temporary files and the `output.txt` file is truncated at the beginning to empty the file. I have used some EXPORT values so that the file names defined in the main part of the script are accessible within the awk routine.

Comment: Thank you! I only had to adjust the regular expression.

Comment: You're welcome. The code is not as clean as I would like it, the main issue is keeping track of how many files have been generated, but if it works for you then that's good.

Comment: @Paul1896 I have updated my code if you want to test it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use text processing command `sed`, cut parts you are needed and echo them into a file. This script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

cert_chain_file="certificate_chain.crt"
private_key_file="private_key.key"
merged_file="merged_cert_and_key.crt"

cert_chain=$(sed -n '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/{:start /END CERTIFICATE/!{N;b start};p}' "$cert_chain_file")

end_cert_line=$(echo "$cert_chain" | grep -m 1 -n "END CERTIFICATE" | cut -d ":" -f 1)

cert_chain_before_end=$(echo "$cert_chain" | head -n "$end_cert_line")

private_key=$(sed -n '/BEGIN PRIVATE KEY/{:start /END PRIVATE KEY/!{N;b start};p}' "$private_key_file")

merged_cert_and_key="${cert_chain_before_end}\n${private_key}${cert_chain#"$cert_chain_before_end"}"

echo -e "$merged_cert_and_key" > "$merged_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the job:

```bash
# concatante two files
cat certificate_chain_file private_key_file > merged_file

# Find first occurance
awk '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {print NR; exit}' merged_file

# insert the private key
sed -i.bak -e '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/r private_key_file' -e '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/d' merged_file

# remove backup file
rm merged_file.bak
```

you can change the format of the file like `merged_file` to `merged_file.bak`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've updated my post with a code snippet. Your sed command only removes the last -----END CERTIFICATE----- in the merged file.